# COUNTIFS one cell doesn't contain any numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I'm trying to tally instances in the "Likes" sheet where two conditions are met in the same row:

- There isa match for search term in Column A, AND
- If there is a match, there are no numbers in Column B of that same row

For example, if this is the "Likes" sheet:
[image]
this is what I'd want to see in my tally roster:

[image]

That is, I don't want to count the submission of user 1234@xyz.org, because there are numbers in the email.

I've tried `=COUNTIFS(Likes!$E$2:$E, $A4, Likes!$B$2:$B, "<>*\d*")`, but my tally is reflecting submissions by users with numbers in their usernames (i.e. I'm seeing a value of 2 reflected for "Bill Clinton"). Any help will be well received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `COUNTIFS()` with `REGEXMATCH()`.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(REGEXMATCH($B$2:$B,"[0-9]")),FALSE,$E$2:$E,H2)
```

To make it dynamic spill formula, use `MAP()` or `BYROW()` function.

```
=MAP(H2:H6,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(INDEX(REGEXMATCH($B$2:$B,"[0-9]")),FALSE,$E$2:$E,x)))
```

Basically `REGEXMATCH($B$2:$B,"[0-9]")` will detect digits in cells and will return true or false. Then you can use `COUNTIFS()` to count false values means no numbers in emails.

[image]